# Proof of the subadditive ergodic theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $\tau:\Omega\to\Omega$ be a measurable map on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with $\operatorname P\circ\:\tau^{-1}=\operatorname P$, $$\mathcal I:=\left\{A\in\mathcal A:\tau^{-1}(A)=A\right\}$$ and $X_n:\Omega\to[-\infty,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable for $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\operatorname E\left[X_1^+\right]<\infty$. Assume $$X_{m+n}\le X_m+X_n\circ\tau^m\;\;\;\text{for all }m,n\in\mathbb N\tag1.$$ It's then trivial to see that $\operatorname E\left[X_n^+\right]\le n\operatorname E\left[X_1^+\right]<\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb N.$

> I would like to show that $$\frac{\operatorname E\left[X_n\right]}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\operatorname E\left[X_n\right]}n\tag2$$ and $$\frac{\operatorname E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal I\right]}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\operatorname E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal I\right]}n\tag3\;\;\;\text{almost surely}.$$ Moreover, and this is the thing I'm struggling with most, $$\frac{X_n}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\operatorname E\left[X_n\mid\mathcal I\right]}n\;\;\;\text{almost surely}\tag4.$$

By Fekete's lemma, $$\frac{x_n}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\inf_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{x_n}n\in[-\infty,\infty)\tag5$$ for any subadditive $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[-\infty,\infty)$. So, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are trivial from this result, since it's easy to see that $(\operatorname E[X_n])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(\operatorname E[X_n\mid\mathcal I])_{n\in\mathbb N}$ are (pointwisely) subadditive.

> Now, in light of the corresponding proof for the [ordinary pointwise ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Probabilistic_formulation:_Birkhoff%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem), we might be able to utilize the subadditive version of the [maximal ergodic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ergodic_theorem): $$\operatorname E\left[X_1;\max_{1\le i\le n}X_i\ge0\right]\ge0\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N.\tag6$$

I guess we are able to reduce the problem to the case where $Y_n\le0$ and $Y_n\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. So, if you know a proof under this assumption, I'm interested in it as well.

Comment: whats ur question? pf of (4)? also, why no ergodic theory tag?

Comment: @mathworker21 The question is: How can we show $(4)$; maybe using an appropriate generalization of the maximal ergodic theorem.

Comment: im confused. is this part of the proof of the subadditive ergodic theorem, and ur asking about a part of it? if so, can you provide the whole proof? if not, is this an exercise about the application of the subadditive ergodic theorem?

Comment: @mathworker21 It's neither a part of an exercise, nor a proof that I'm following. I'm just trying to proof the subadditive ergodic theorem this way. Almost every proof which I've found is quite lengthy, since it mimics many basic results which hold in much greater generality. I think that it can be proved in a much easier way, if one establishes an appropriate version of the maximal ergodic theorem first.